# Deleting all files in a folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files, temp

I am trying to make a program in Python that will delete all files in the `%temp%` path, also known as `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp`.

How can I do this? I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: note: On POSIX, a temporary directory may have a sticky bit set: [*"When a directory's sticky bit is set, the filesystem treats the files in such directories in a special way so only the file's owner, the directory's owner, or root user can rename or delete the file."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) i.e., you might not have permission to delete all files in the temporary directory.

Comment: I don't believe this particular question is a duplicate as the OP is asking about temporary folder deletion.  The linked answer doesn't reference the temp folder.  For temp files, you can use the tempfile module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove tempfile in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793080/how-to-remove-tempfile-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you could use [`shutil.rmtree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to delete all files/directories in a folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shutil
import tempfile

dirpath = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    # use the temporary directory here
    ...
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(dirpath) # clean up
```

The above can be written simpler if it is all you need (create a temporary directory from scratch):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dir:
    print(dir.name) # use the temporary directory here
```